# Como puedo hacer que al cargar la pagina, se ejecute el jquery como corresponde

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Resulta que tengo un código de filtrado de divs, el cual me muestra uno u otro elemento, el filtrado lo hago con jQuery, el problema es que quiero que al iniciar la carga de la pagina, no me muestre todas las opciones, si no que no me muestre ninguna y al seleccionar una de las opciones muestre por filtrado correcto

El código es el sgte:

```js
$(document).ready()
  $('#tipoImpresora').change(function () {
     var year = $(this).val();
     $("div").hide();
     $("div:contains('" + year + "')").show();
  });
```

```css
div {
  background: #eee;
  height: 300px;
  width: 280px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <select id="tipoImpresora">
   <option value="0">ninguno</option>
   <option value="Impresora Laser" selected="true">laser</option>
   <option value="Impresora Tinta">tinta</option>
  </select>
 </form>

    <div class="Laser" style="background-color: red;">
   <p>Impresora Laser</p>
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <br>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Marca</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Modelo</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Color Tinta</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <button>Seleccionar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="Tinta" style="background-color: blue;">
   <p>Impresora Tinta</p>
   <img src="#">
   <img src="#">
   <br>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Marca</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Modelo</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Color Tinta</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <br>
   <button>Seleccionar</button>
  </div>
```

Resulta que al cargar la pagina me muestra el bloque rojo y el azul, y no quiero que me muestre ninguno salvo que haga mi primera elección en el select.

Comment: el `$(document).ready()` lo tienes mal escrito. es  `$(document).ready( function () { ... });` y donde los 3 puntos lo que quieres que se ejecute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre te va a mostrar los div si no los ocultas de primeras con:

```
style="display:none"
```

Comment: tuve problema poniendo 2 display, pero lo solucione, teniendo por css el inline-block y dentro de cada div un display:none para que se ejecutara uno antes del otro, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Como comenta @lois6b, el `$(document).ready(function(){...})` está mal escrito. Además, lo ideal sería usar `$(function(){...});`

Por otro lado, para ocultar los divs inicialmente puedes simplemente usar:

```
 $("div.Laser").hide();
 $("div.Tinta").hide();
```

Además deberías poner la opción "ninguno" como `selected` ya que tiene más sentido si desde el principio quieres ocultar los dos divs:

```js
$(function(){
        $("div.Laser").hide();
        $("div.Tinta").hide();
        
      $('#tipoImpresora').change(function () {
         var year = $(this).val();
         $("div").hide();
         $("div:contains('" + year + "')").show();
      });
        
});
```

```css
div {
      background: #eee;
      height: 300px;
      width: 280px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <select id="tipoImpresora">
       <option value="0" selected="true">ninguno</option>
       <option value="Impresora Laser">laser</option>
       <option value="Impresora Tinta">tinta</option>
      </select>
     </form>

        <div class="Laser" style="background-color: red;">
       <p>Impresora Laser</p>
       <img src="#">
       <img src="#">
       <br>
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Marca</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Modelo</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Color Tinta</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <br>
       <button>Seleccionar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="Tinta" style="background-color: blue;">
       <p>Impresora Tinta</p>
       <img src="#">
       <img src="#">
       <br>
       <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Marca</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Modelo</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>Color Tinta</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="txtMarca"></td>
        </tr>
       </table>
       <br>
       <button>Seleccionar</button>
      </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido el $(document).ready() se puede simplificar poniendo solo el $(), de todas maneras tambien fue una respuesta valida, la cosa es que el display: none me funciono mejor sin tanto jaleo

Comment: El $() es lo que he puesto :). Respecto al display:none es practicamente lo mismo que hacer el hide(), aunque hay que tener en cuenta que con hide() jQuery recuerda el estado anterior. Aquí más info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396983/hide-or-display-none-jquery

Comment: Las dos primeras lineas te aconesejaría que las editases, ya que el dato no se corresponde con la realidad, quitando eso, buena respuesta :)

Comment: Gracias, ¿a qué te refieres exactamente con "el dato no se corresponde con la realidad"?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ocultar los divs por defecto con CSS aplicándole `display: none`.

Otra opción seria disparar el evento `change` al elemento `select` para establecer primeramente el valor que quieres de la siguiente manera:

```
$('#tipoImpresora')
    .val('0')
    .trigger('change');
```

Comment: Hola Alejandro. Puedes pulsar en Copiar a respuesta para tu luego modificar el snippet y añadir tu codigo :P  Asi quedará mejor.  Un saludo